# Trying to insert image from database onto news blog above each entry using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a website and would like to allow an admin to add an image that is being pulled from a MySQL database and have it display above the news blog text that is being added as well. I can get it to display the images, as well as the text, but they are grouped together (images with images and text with text). How can I have my website display a the last image entered above the last text entry added?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT imageId FROM output_images ORDER BY imageId DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
<div class="brown-container-fluid text-left">
    <div class="text-home">
        <h2><strong>Pine Lane News</strong></h2><br/>

        <?php
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <img style="max-width:300px; max-height:300px;"
                     src="imageView.php?image_id=<?php echo $row["imageId"]; ?>"/><br/>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY date_entered DESC';

        if ($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) { // Run the query.

            // Retrieve and print every record:
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

                print
                    "<dl><dt><h3><strong>{$row['title']}</strong></h3></dt>
    <dd>{$row['entry']}<br /><br />\n</dd></dl>";
            }

        } else { // Query didn't run.
            print '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the data because:<br />' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
        } // End of query IF.

        mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _If_ you know that you will get the same number of results from each query, you can fetch _all_ of the results from one, and then while iterating through the other, access the row from the first resultset with the same index as the current row in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Something I came up with real quick, not tested.

```
<?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo '<div style="text-align:center;">';
            echo '<img style="max-width:300px; max-height:300px;"';
            echo 'src="imageView.php?image_id="'.$row["imageId"].'"/><br/>';
            echo '</div>';

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY date_entered DESC LIMIT 1';

            if ($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) { // Run the query.
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))

                {

                print
                    "<dl><dt><h3><strong>{$row['title']}</strong></h3></dt>
    <dd>{$row['entry']}<br /><br />\n</dd></dl>";
            }

        } else { // Query didn't run.
            print '<p style="color: red;">Could not retrieve the data because:<br />' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '.</p><p>The query being run was: ' . $query . '</p>';
        } // End of query IF.

        mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
        ?>
```

Comment: This would fetch the same row from `entries` for each `output_images` entry.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah I didn't catch that earlier... rookie mistake. Just saw your comment and it seems like that would be the only way to go